# How to get html dynamic table data in response of jmeter

Tags: html, jmeter, response, performance-testing, hidden

I am using the JMeter for the testing the application.

In the same, I have visited some page where the dynamic table contents should be displayed on the response data in view results.

However except that HTML dynamic table I am able to view the other contents so please help for getting the contents of the dynamic table too.

I have tried to get it using regular expression also have tried to get it with XPath extract. It goes till the `<thead>` tag, however, doesn't view the values in the `<tbody>`.

1. [Here I have wanted to get the trains details. As the table is dynamic we should be able to get the values in the response of jmeter. However I am not able to get this contents.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbDg2.png)
2. [In the same i tried to get the values of the special trains page using XPath so it gives me error of Illegal expression.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFlCt.png)
3. [Screenshot no.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cSkjJ.png)

I have not used any different library to get the html table data values.

I have tried to get the table contents by using the table it in regular expression

Xpath Query: "/html/body/table/tbody/tr[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFlCt.png)/td/div"
Reference name: Special_trains

so it gives the output java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 77: http://enquiry.indianrail.gov.in/ntes/specialTrains.jsp?scrollerDivSpltrn=Not found

In the same the div id is: "scrollerDivSpltrn"
Hence need the answer

Comment: Can you show some response sample?

Comment: is there different library being use to plot the table? or share sample response?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to extract the table id properly. Once you are able to extract the that id, you should be able to fetch dynamic table.